# Me da un error cuando quiero importar android.support.v7.Toolbar

Tags: android

[image: Error cuando tengo que importar V7<code>import android.support.v7.*;</code>]
Hola gente, cuando intento importar el Toolbar me da un error, no me encuentra v7, solo tengo v4.

Comment: Si no tienes `v7` y quieres usarlo es evidente que tienes que agregarlo en el gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando [**AndroidX**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar), el import correcto para usar el [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar) debe ser:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```